# .NET MySqlDataAdapter Fill Performance

Tags: mysql, .net, vb.net

I've got a performance issue retrieving data from a MySQL database using the MySqlDataAdapter.Fill() Method and I can just don't understand why.

Here's my VB.NET code I use to retrieve the data:

```
Dim DBda As New MySqlDataAdapter(command)
        Try
            connection.Open()
            DBda.Fill(DBds, table)
            connection.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw ex
        Finally
            If Not IsNothing(command) AndAlso Not IsNothing(command.Connection) AndAlso command.Connection.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
                command.Connection.Close()
                MySqlConnection.ClearPool(command.Connection)
            End If
        End Try
```

Though this is just a portion of the whole method, it is the relevant part.

The Fill method here takes 10 seconds to retrieve 3510 rows.

The same query in the MySQL Workbench just takes 0.016 Duration / 1.578 fetch.

I tried to change the code using MySqlDataReader (with its various differnt approaches) instead of the adapter, but it takes roughly the same time.

The database has the proper indexes on the relevant columns. I don't think that's the problem since the query is much faster on the DBMS.

Here's the query which is used:

```
SELECT `Mail`.`MailID`,
`Mail`.`FromAddress`,
`Mail`.`ToAddress`,
`Mail`.`ReplyTo`,
`Mail`.`Cc`,
`Mail`.`Bcc`,
`Mail`.`Subject`,
`Mail`.`BodyPlain`,
`Mail`.`SentDate`,
`Mail`.`ReceivedDate`,
`Mail`.`IsOutMail`,
`Mail`.`Priority`,
`Mail`.`IsDeleted`,
`Mail`.`IsDraft`,
`Mail`.`MailFolderID`,
`Mail`.`MailAccountID`,
`Mail`.`AttachmentNames`,
`Mail`.`MessageID`,
`Mail`.`MessageUID`,
`Mail`.`SenderUserID`,
`Mail`.`MailDisplayName`,
`Mail`.`IsMarked`,
`Mail`.`IsSpam`,
`Mail`.`MailSize` FROM `Mail` where MailAccountId=7 OR MailAccountID=9;
```

Today I read a LOT of postings, approaches and turtorials through out the web, but I still have no clue why the Fill method is take so long.

I would be so happy, if anyone has an idea, which could direct me the proper way to find the solution.

Thanks!

Comment: Generally, a DataAdapter will be faster than filling a table using a DataReader (but not enough that it matters until 10s of thousands of rows).   Workbench is not creating DataRows and so forth, so it is not a direct comparison. 10 secs is a bit much - mine just loaded 125k rows in 2.8 secs

Comment: Instead of using your existing dataset/datatable try creating a new one and see if it loads faster. It may be that you've got binding enabled which is causing large scale refreshing / extra processing

Comment: @FloatingKiwi: The instances of the dataset, adapter etc. are always created anew when the method is executed.

Comment: Try using a profier then and see if anything strikes you as odd. If may just be that you're loading a lot of large emails. (Maybe exclude the body fields and profile the timing). Although workbench loads quickly it may be that it only loads the first n records, then grabs the others as required.

Comment: @FloatingKiwi: Yeah, I'll try a profiler. I was about to do that anyway. The body/attachments etc. are already excluded. It's jsut some integers, bools and strings that are being loaded, Thanks for the tipp anyway :-)

Comment: By default, Workbench only selects the first 1000 rows unless you changed that in the settings...but it still doesnt do the same work an adapter does.  You also dont *need* to create a new Adapter each time - they are meant to do much more than just fill DataSet/Datatables

Comment: @Plutonix: I've changed the config. The results are not limited by the work bench.

Comment: Found the issue. It actually was a rather "big" column which slowed it down. One column can hold huge strings which was responsible for the delay. I now load that column async. Done the trick.